# The attached virtio disk is not recognized by libvirt but it is recognized by qemu

Tags: qemu, uefi, kvm, arm, libvirt

I'm trying to virtualize FreeBSD 13.2 for arm 32 bit on my laptop ARM Chromebook where qemu is version 5.1,KVM is enabled,libvirt and virt-manager are installed from the source code and everything works great. The host OS is Devuan 5. Infact,using these parameters,FreeBSD is able to boot entirely :

```
UEFICODE=/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF32_CODE.fd
UEFIVARS=/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF32_VARS.fd
DISK=/Dati/img/FreeBSD-13.2-RELEASE-arm-armv7-GENERICSD.img

qemu-system-arm -enable-kvm -serial stdio -m 1024 -M virt -cpu cortex-a15 
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file=$UEFICODE 
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1,file=$UEFIVARS 
-drive file=$DISK,media=disk,format=raw 
-device i82559b,netdev=net0,mac="52:54:00:12:34:55" 
-netdev type=user,id=net0 -device virtio-gpu-pci -usb 
-device nec-usb-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse 
-device vmware-svga,id=video0,vgamem_mb=16
```

As you can see from this boot log messages :

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VBtJ5bTTCz/

So,this argument is good because qemu recognizes the virtio disk :

```
-drive file=$DISK,media=disk,format=raw \
```

but these arguments used by libvirt aren't able to boot FreeBSD because the virtio disk attached is not recognized (I also tried with a SATA disk and it is not recognized as well) :

```
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
  <source file="/Dati/img/FreeBSD-13.2-RELEASE-arm-armv7-GENERICSD.img"/>
  <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>
```

Here you can see what are the full XML code used by libirt :

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hpGmgp2773/

this is the portion of code that correspond with the virtio disk (the FreeBSD image file)

[image: 1]

What's the difference between the qemu and the libvirt parameters ? Do you have some vague idea about the reason ? I think the problem is caused by qemu and/or libvirt.

I tried to boot the image going inside the bios settings and trying to boot directly the image disk,but I saw this error :

[image: 2]

If you want to see the whole boot sequence,you can give a look at this short video that I have recorded :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kRoAFH_6DH-vNEmNmg4PEQ8lQmKZnUi2/view